Circle packing with discrete points
I was looking to attempt a different method to solve a circle packing problem. More specifically, packing n circles in a rectangle with the goal to have the circles be as large as possible. There is a great post discussing this problem here http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/05/knapsack-packing-difficult-miqcp.html, but I wanted to solve it using HiGHS and as an MILP.
With that said, this is the formulation I came up with.  Is this right?
$$
\begin{alignat}{8}
\text{max}  & \sum_i R_i \\\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & R_i \le |rect_{length} - px_i| \quad \forall i \\\\
& R_i \le px_i \quad \forall i \\\\
& R_i \le |rect_{width} - py_i| \quad \forall i \\\\
& R_i \le py_i \quad \forall i \\\\
& D_{ij} \ge R_i + R_j - (1-y_i)M - (1-y_j)M \quad \forall i,j \\\\
& \sum_i y_i = n \\\\
&R_i \ge 0 \quad \forall i \\\\
& y_i \in \{0, 1\} \quad \forall i
\end{alignat}
$$
A few comments:

I create a mesh grid of points. I recognize I lose some accuracy here, but the hope is the MILP solves quickly.
$D_{ij}$ is a parameter that is calculated before the optimization, possible since Im using discrete points between $[(0, rect_{length}), (0, rect_{width})]$.
Parameters used are: 11 grid points, $rect_{length} = rect_{width} = 10$, $M=10$, n=10
I dont do all $i,j$ combinations, I only do $i<j$
Final model size is 1414 rows, 163 cols, 5572 nonzeros
Using HiGHS Im unable to close the gap (~36% after 300 seconds). Best solution found is 14.84.


Not sure if its helpful, but here is some code I used for building out the $px,py$ data.
import numpy as np

linear_grid_points = 11
xmax = 10
ymax = 10
x_grid = np.linspace(0, xmax, linear_grid_points)
y_grid = np.linspace(0, ymax, linear_grid_points)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)
locs = np.vstack((xv.ravel(), yv.ravel())).T

dist = locs[:, :, None] - locs[:, :, None].T
dist = (dist * dist).sum(1)
dist = np.sqrt(dist)

circles_to_use = 10


You have the correct optimal objective value, but you seem to have omitted constraints that enforce $y_i=0 \implies R_i = 0$.  The absolute values are redundant.  To make the notation a bit simpler, let your candidate circle centers be $(x_i,y_i)$, let the rectangle be $[0,\bar{x}]\times[0,\bar{y}]$, and rename your binary $y_i$ variable as $z_i$.  Let $\bar{R}_i=\min(x_i,\bar{x}-x_i,y_i,\bar{y}-y_i)$. The problem is to maximize $\sum_i R_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
z_i = 0 &\implies R_i = 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1\\
(z_i = 1 \land z_j = 1) &\implies R_i + R_j \le D_{ij} &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag2\label2\\
\sum_i z_i &= n \tag3\label3\\
0 \le R_i &\le \bar{R}_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4\\
z_i &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for all $i$} \tag5\label5
\end{align}
You can linearize \eqref{1} via big-M constraint
\begin{align}R_i &\le \bar{R}_i z_i &&\text{for all $i$}\tag{6}\label{6}\end{align}
You can linearize \eqref{2}, as you did with a different $M$, via big-M constraint \begin{align}R_i + R_j - D_{ij} \le \max(\bar{R}_i - D_{ij}, \bar{R}_j - D_{ij}, -D_{ij}/2)(2-z_i-z_j) &&\text{for all $i<j$} \tag{7}\label{7}\end{align}
Here's another optimal solution:


To get an upper bound on the objective value for the problem without restricting the centers to grid points, you can solve the second-order cone programming problem of maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^n R_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \pi R_i^2 &\le \bar{x} \bar{y} \\
R_i &\ge 0 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}
The resulting optimal solution is $$R_i = \sqrt{\frac{\bar{x} \bar{y}}{n\pi}},$$ with objective value $\sqrt{n\bar{x}\bar{y}/\pi}$. For the given problem data, this is approximately $17.84124$.

Thanks Rob for catching my mistake! Thankfully the model had this incorporated, missed it when typing it up though.

For your optimal solution, is it the same objective value?

Yes, 14.841619253
